# Why are the results of the optimization on aliasing different for char* and std::string&?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization, strict-aliasing, restrict-qualifier

```cpp
void f1(int* count, char* str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < *count; ++i) str[i] = 0;
}

void f2(int* count, char8_t* str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < *count; ++i) str[i] = 0;
}

void f3(int* count, char* str) {
  int n = *count;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) str[i] = 0;
}

void f4(int* __restrict__ count, char* str) { // GCC extension; clang also supports it
  for (int i = 0; i < *count; ++i) str[i] = 0;
}
```

According to [this article](https://vector-of-bool.github.io/2022/05/11/char8-memset.html),
the compiler (almost) replaces `f2()` with a call to `memset()`,
however, the compiler generates machine code from `f1()` that is almost identical to the above code.
Because the compiler can assume that `count` and `str` do not point to the same `int` object (*strict aliasing rule*) in `f2()`,
but cannot make such an assumption in `f1()` (C++ allow aliasing any pointer type with a `char*`).

Such aliasing problems can be avoided by dereferencing `count` in advance, as in `f3()`, or by using `__restrict__`, as in `f4()`.

https://godbolt.org/z/fKTjcnW5f

The following functions are `std::string`/`std::u8string` version of the above functions:

```cpp
void f5(int* count, std::string& str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < *count; ++i) str[i] = 0;
}

void f6(int* count, std::u8string& str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < *count; ++i) str[i] = 0;
}

void f7(int* count, std::string& str) {
  int n = *count;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) str[i] = 0;
}

void f8(int* __restrict__ count, std::string& str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < *count; ++i) str[i] = 0;
}

void f9(int* __restrict__ count, std::string& __restrict__ str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < *count; ++i) str[i] = 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nsPdfhzoj

My questions are:

1. `f5()` and `f6()` are the same result as `f1()` and `f2()`, respectively.
   However, `f7()` and `f8()` do not have the same result as `f3()` and `f4()` (`memset()` was not used). Why?
2. The compiler replaces `f9()` with a call to `memset()` (that does not happen with `f8()`). Why?

Tested with GCC 12.1 on x86_64, `-std=c++20 -O3`.

Comment: IMHO "why" is not a right question. All optimisations are optional implementations up to a compiler. Also `restrict` applied to a single argument is not very useful hint to a compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a simplified demo for the `string` case:

```
class String {
    char* data_;
public:
    char& operator[](size_t i) { return data_[i]; }
};

void f(int n, String& s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) s[i] = 0;
}
```

The problem here is that the compiler cannot know whether writing to `data_[i]` does not change the value of `data_`. With the restricted `s` parameter, you tell the compiler that this cannot happen.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/jjn9d3Mxe

This is not necessary for passing a pointer, since it is passed in the register, so it cannot be aliased with the pointed-to data. However, if this pointer is a global variable, the same problem occurs.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Y3nWvn6rW

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that your std::string implementation internally has a `char *`, since that is the default type for the string template. That char * is accessed in `str[i]` and being a `char *` can alias with any other pointer or reference, specifically with your `str`. So every time `str[i] = 0` is evaluated the str object might change.

Not so when you restrict `str`.

Answer (score 0):

When the first C STandard was written, character types in C and C++ were widely used for three purposes:

1. Storing actual text characters.
2. Holding small numbers.
3. Accessing the raw bits in the storage underlying other types.

There is no particular reason why objects and pointers that are used for the first two purposes should have any kind of special aliasing rules, but the authors of the Standard wanted to make sure that aliasing rules wouldn't interfere with the use of character types for the third purpose.

A better way of accommodating the latter construct would have been to say that in contexts where a compiler can see that a `T*` is converted to `U*`, accesses performed via the `U*` will be recognized as possibly being performed "by" lvalues of type `T`.  Applying such principles would eliminate the need for the "character type exception".  Nonetheless, the fact that character types are sometimes used for the third purpose above has resulted in them having special rules which would not make sense if applied to other constructs that are only used for the first two purposes.